# Taking a change from another user

Tags: discussion

When editing a question, afterwards (if approved) it will display who edited the question. Recently as I have been editing questions - being grammar/spelling police **;-)** - I've noticed that (SOME OF) the high reputation users that have been - for a lack of better terms - stealing the change. They might go in and replace a word with a similar word then approve the edit, so I might have edited upwards of 100 lines, but they edit 1 word and get the credit (Their name is displayed as editing the question). Now this isn't a technical issue, and isn't a real bother, but I tend to be competitive about everything (yes even S.E.) and this seems like a kind of strange system.

Comment: Reviewing edits *isn't* funny either, and 2K+ users don't even get reputation for that. And when they approve and edit they usually improve more than a word. Shall we credit them at least by leaving their name under the edit for their effort? :)

Comment: @kos I won't name names but around an hour ago I edited over 400 characters in a body, then a user changed in the machine -> inserted and took the credit. I realize that yes most users don't do this but when people do it's annoying AF

Comment: @DavidCole You may be confused about the editors name being on a question,IMO it is not to give credit, it is for other users to see who last revised a post so they can take action if they mus, I almost guarantee you 90% of all edits you will  ever make will get revised at some point and your name will be gone, you are looking for credit in the wrong place, your credit for editing is in badges not your name plastered all over the site. Also if this happens a lot and you think you are being targeted for this by someone, please do name names.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Depending on your definition of "Credit": Not true!  We don't get the reputation points, you do!

But that's only if we choose <kbd>Approve and edit</kbd> instead of <kbd>Reject and edit</kbd>

Actually anyone above 2000 rep doesn't get any reputation points for approving any edits nor for editing, so enjoy the rep while it lasts...

<sub>We still get our name as last editor below the question or answer that was edited though! So if you mean *that* by "credit": yes, we do get the credit... <sup>until someone else gets it in a subsequent edit...</sup>  **;-)**</sub>

Comment: Oh yes, sorry I will re-word. I just get PO-ed when someone elses name shows up instead of mine :) XD

Comment: Yeah, the first few times you will be, after the 10th time you'll be less PO and after the 100th, you won't even care any more!  **;-)**  E.G.: try editing this answer and see if I care!

Comment: Oh, and putting a nice little ☑ if the answer helped is appreciated here on meta too (takes away work from the *real mods*)  **:P** @DavidCole

Comment: @DavidCole your name still shows up in the revision history, just not as the last editor (since you weren't the last editor).

Comment: @Seth yes I know but people usually don't spend time looking at revision history, they look at the one user who edited it last

Comment: @DavidCole: Like I said: The first few times you'll be PO, then you won't mind any more...  The only other way of keeping your name there forever is to make a ***perfect edit!***  **:P ;-)**

Comment: @Fabby True, but what is a ***"perfect"*** edit? Even if there were no flaws, someone could still come in and steal it :P

Comment: @DavidCole I upvoted both the question and answer.  I believe the question was valid.  The user thought he was loosing something and spoke up.    The answer provided, that the user isn't loosing `credit` for his contribution and gave advice of how he may `soon notice this`.  Easily getting PO's is something that we hope our gurus learn to control.  The community could loose what I consider our main intent (to serve) if we are more focused on fighting and rivalry than making positive contributions.  Hopefully this question and answer will ease the pain of others who are feeling similar anguish.

Comment: @L.D.James: another <s>old fart</s> person with a lot of experience!  **;-)**